# Capturing non-jira email ids in custom fields

Tags: jira

I have checked the following solution in stackoverflow:

[Jira for bug tracking and customer support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272864/jira-for-bug-tracking-and-customer-support)

However the custom fields are not populated with the e-mail id as desired. Not sure if i have placed the scripts in the right folder and also if there is any other issue with the script. I am totally alien to scripting. I am trying to get this custom field populated using the script then send notification to customer with the issue id. I have placed the script in the Atlassian\JIRA\atlassian-jira\WEB-INF\classes\custom\listeners folder location. The custom fields.groovy file, create_issue.groovy file and new_case.template are placed in this location. I have added these to the post function in the following order:

Create issue originally
Create issue.groovy from the [Jira for bug tracking and customer support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272864/jira-for-bug-tracking-and-customer-support)
Create issue.groovy from the [Jira for bug tracking and customer support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272864/jira-for-bug-tracking-and-customer-support)
new_case.template from the [Jira for bug tracking and customer support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272864/jira-for-bug-tracking-and-customer-support)

Note: I have not changed any line in the script provided in [Jira for bug tracking and customer support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272864/jira-for-bug-tracking-and-customer-support).
I have just used what is present there

Answer (score 0):

wrote the original post, to use this scripts you need to install the [Jira script runner plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner). Than, add the scripts to workflow transitions, in the right place. For example, the *Create issues by email* script should be attached to the `create` transition (the first transition in the workflow).

If you still have problems let me know.